# Appropriate use of Mockito.reset()?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

From `Mockito.reset()` documentation:

> Smart Mockito users hardly use this feature because they know it could be a sign of poor tests. Normally, you don't need to reset your mocks, just create new mocks for each test method.
>   Instead of reset() please consider writing simple, small and focused test methods over lengthy, over-specified tests.

I have servicemethod which is called from the frontend, with a DTO containing 3 Booleans as the only argument - let's call them `a`, `b` and `c`:

```
public void executeService(AbcDTO dto) { (...) }
```

Depending on the values of the Booleans, the service then calls `aManager.a()`, `bManager.b()` and `cManager.c()`. Indeed, I could do this in 3 separate servicemethods, but I'd rather not.

I wanted to unittest every possible combination of the booleanvalues `a`, `b` and `c`, so I wrote something like:

```
@Test
public void testABC() {
    // Mock aManager, bManager, cManager
    for(boolean a : asSet(true, false)) {
        for(boolean b : asSet(true, false)) {
            for(boolean c : asSet(true, false)) {
                AbcDTO dto = new AbcDTO(a, b, c);

                service.executeService(dto);

                verify(aManager, times(a ? 1 : 0)).a();
                verify(bManager, times(b ? 1 : 0)).b();
                verify(cManager, times(c ? 1 : 0)).c();
                reset(aManager, bManager, cManager);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think this is a test which clearly indicates the purpose of `executeService` for future readers, but it only runs green with `Mockito.reset()`. After reading the documentation, I'm not sure if this is the way to go.

I believe I have two options:

- Use `Mockito.reset()`
- Write separate unittests for each combination (so 8 tests with lots of copy-pasting)

**Question:**
Is this a correct, acceptable use of `Mockito.reset()`, or should I go with the separate tests?

Comment: You could put the stuff inside the loop body in a helper method, which is also responsible for creating mocks.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to try using [parameterized tests](https://blogs.oracle.com/jacobc/entry/parameterized_unit_tests_with_junit) or [the zohhak framework](https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak) so that you have 1 test run for each combination of boolean values. In that case, there's no need to reset the mocks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use TestNG you might want to take a look at DataProviders.
Here's a good example: https://www.toolsqa.com/testng/testng-dataproviders/